# looping through with a function to generate coordinates for PGFPlots graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

Is there a way to loop through with a function in pgfplots to generate a set of coordinates? So far I've done the manual way of just inputting values, but this will quickly get tedious as I want to plot different parameter plots for the same function.

I tried using the `\foreach` function, but it doesn't want to compile. What's the best way of achieving this? Below is my code, first function plot with manual input works, the second looped plot does not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\b,\vo,\v,\a)=ceil((\b*(\v-\vo))/\a)+1;}]
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=acceleration ($a_0$),
        ylabel=number of yellow bars($y$)
        ]
    %this works
    \addplot coordinates{
        (-0.5,{f(1,30,10,-0.5)})
        (-1,{f(1,30,10,-1)})
        (-1.5,{f(1,30,10,-1.5)})
        (-2,{f(1,30,10,-2)})
        (-2.5,{f(1,30,10,-2.5)})
        (-3,{f(1,30,10,-3)})
    };
    %this does not work
    \addplot coordinates{
        \foreach \acc in {-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2,-2.5,-3} {
            (\acc,{f(1,40,20,\acceler)})
        }
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `samples at` it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\b,\vo,\v,\a)=ceil((\b*(\v-\vo))/\a)+1;}]
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=acceleration ($a_0$),
        ylabel=number of yellow bars($y$)
        ]
    %this works
%     \addplot coordinates{
%         (-0.5,{f(1,30,10,-0.5)})
%         (-1,{f(1,30,10,-1)})
%         (-1.5,{f(1,30,10,-1.5)})
%         (-2,{f(1,30,10,-2)})
%         (-2.5,{f(1,30,10,-2.5)})
%         (-3,{f(1,30,10,-3)})
%     };
    %this also works
    \addplot[mark=*,color=blue,samples at={-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2,-2.5,-3}] {f(1,40,20,x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]